# Why can't Kotlin infer return type of a Boolean expression using ==?

Tags: kotlin, warnings

From what I understand, Kotlin should be able to infer the return type of a function based on the last expression used in the function body.

```
fun returnInt() {
    42 + 24
}
```

However, when I create a function expecting the result of an equality (==) operation such as:

```
fun returnBoolean() {
    someBool == otherBool
}
```

I get the following warning:

> Unused equals expression

I can resolve this by adding a return type and a return statement:

```
fun returnBoolean(): Boolean {
    return someBool == otherBool
}
```

But I was just wondering why `returnBoolean()` gets an 'Unused equals expression' and `returnInt()` does not.

Comment: I don't know kotlin, but it seems like your `42 + 42` is invalid, and the second piece of code that raises the error is more correct. It seems that with definitions using `{}`, you require an explicit `return`.

Comment: Your first function is not inferred as an `Int`, Kotlin infers that as `Unit`.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me.

Kotlin is able to infer such statements using an equals sign in the function declaration:

```
fun returnInt() =
    42 + 24


fun returnBoolean() =
    someBool == otherBool
```

As a beginner to Kotlin, I find it interesting that `returnInt()` does not get a warning, but if you try to use it during runtime (in my case I passed it as an argument to `java.lang.String.format`), it will throw an exception.

Comment: your returnInt method does not return Int - it just adds two numbers together and does nothing with them. The ```fun stuff() = ...``` notation equals ```fun stuff() { return ... }```. In both cases in your first post you're missing a ```return```

Comment: Call to `returnInt` shouldn't throw an exception. Are you sure your are passing `returnInt()` to `String.format` and not method reference `returnInt`?